# Gutenberg core/file add style support in js/ json

Tags: javascript, block-editor, json

I try add style support for file block in gutenberg.

my code work for UL/li list:

```
wp.blocks.registerBlockStyle('core/list', {
    name: 'blue-circle',
    label: 'Blue Circle',
});
```

I try add:

```
wp.blocks.registerBlockStyle('core/file', {
    name: 'test-inline',
    label: 'test-inline',
});
```

no work for file block.
Anyone know how I can add support for file block?  <s>on the core HTML block?</s>

Thanks!

Comment: what code did you try for the file block? Can you edit it into your question? Did you mean to say "or the core HTML block"?

Comment: Hi, im soryy no need html block. 

only need similar UL code <ul class="is-style-Blue-Circle"> eg.: <div class="is-my-style wp-block-file">

Comment: when you tried it for the core file block and it didn't work, what code did you use? Can you edit your question to include it? It's very difficult to fix your code if we cannot see it

Comment: I have online working code for ul list. This code no show style in file block: 
wp.blocks.registerBlockStyle('core/file', {
    name: 'test-inline',
    label: 'test-inline',
});

Comment: are you sure? Because if i insert a file block, then copy paste your code into the browser dev tools console, a toggle appears in the sidebar with "Default" and "test-inline", how are you adding this code and how are you testing it? Because it looks like you've already found the answer but are probably making a silly mistake that's too obvious to see, can you share which file this JS is in, when where and how it runs, as well as what PHP code is used to add it